K6browser authentication on azure
Can someone provide any example on how to authenticate using k6browser and azure? I found that all of code samples are on how to authenticate but for backend requests, however it seems that its not working like that for k6browser. I used authentication example from here: https://grafana.com/docs/k6/latest/examples/oauth-authentication/
So im receiving token but how to include it into my browser script, so far i tried this :
export default async function () {
  const auth = authenticateAzure(httpx);
  const page = await browser.newPage(); 
  page.addHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${auth}`); // ????
  sleep(1);
  try {
    await page.goto('https://test.com/');
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshots/screenshot.png' });
  } finally {
    await page.close();
  }
}

